# Threejs: Can I change a face color in PlaneGeometry based on vertex value?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to programatically change the color of a face than pre-creating a pallet of materials and then assign based on the vertex value? I have this:

```
var materials = [];
materials.push([..] //add all the materials here.

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(gs, gs, size, size);
$.getJSON('http://localhost:5000', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
        geometry.vertices[i].z = data.map[i] / 255;
        if (geometry.vertices[i].z > 1) {
            geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
        } else {
            geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    scene.add(plane);
});
```

Would like something like:

```
[..]
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000', function (data) {
        for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
            geometry.vertices[i].z = data.map[i] / 255;
            if (geometry.vertices[i].z > 1) {
                geometry.faces[i].setrgb(i*128, i*2, i*96);
            } else {
                geometry.faces[i].setrgb(i*12, i*2, i*96);
            }
        }
[..]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example

```
var size = 10; // just for example
...
planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(size, size, 10, 10);
...
planeGeom.faces.forEach(function(face){
  var val = planeGeom.vertices[face.a].y;
  face.color.setRGB(Math.abs(val) / size * 2, 0, 0);
});
planeGeom.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

if you want to set color with `r`, `g`, `b` components, then values of components must be from 0 to 1, not from 0 to 255. Each face is of [`Face3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Face3) type, which has properties `a`, `b`, `c`, where indices of vertices stored.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/axmwqhgw/)

Comment: Related question, how can i access the corresponding vertex x/y/z value of each face inside the foreach face loop? Dont see face to have an array of corresponding vertex, face array and vertex array are different structures inside geometry.